# Cross-domain proxy in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebook, proxy, cross-domain

I'm looking for a solution/gem/plugin to proxy load the HTML of any site with JS. I'm making something like Facebook's status update (add link) form which crawls the link for images which will be displayed as a thumbnail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fetch pages you have a lot of choices, everything from `Net::HTTP` which is part of Rails core, to the `curb` gem which employs the `curl` library.

If you want to parse the pages you get to extract the images you can use the `nokogiri` gem which will allow you to parse the HTML using CSS selectors.

If you're doing a lot of these requests and don't want the full overhead of Rails for what should be a simple proxy, you could always implement this using the `sinatra` gem, which is a much more light-weight model. Sinatra can be built into a full Rails app using the Rack infrastructure system so it fits in seamlessly.

Comment: I was experimenting with Curb and then I found Nokogiri. It's great!

Comment: Nokogiri is actually pretty amazing and using CSS selectors to grab chunks of HTML feels like the best way to do it for most situations.